# How to get first element name of the SOAP Body using XSLT?

Tags: xslt

```
<soap:envelope>
  <soap:body>
    <ns:Hello>11</ns:Hello>
    <ns1:hai>12</ns1:hai>
  </soap:body>
</soap:envelope>
```

from above i need to get first element name from the body root tag i.e, need to get output as a 'Hello'. Please help me, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

**Use**:

```
local-name(/*/*/*[1])
```

**It is recommended to avoid using the `//` XPath pseudo-operator** whenever the structure of the XML document is statically known, because many XPath engines evaluate it inefficiently (by traversing a complete (sub)tree).

Answer (score 1):

```
<xsl:value-of select="local-name(//soap:body/*[1])" />
```